# How to get BuildConfig in multi module app

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I am quite new with android and now building some multi module android app. In my app module in build.gradle i set product flavors and i put there some variables for each environment. Now I have login module where I would like to read some of those variables. Any idea or advice how to get access to them from different module?

Comment: Don't do that. The App's `BuildConfig` belongs to the app, modules are seperate entities that are supposed to work with any app module, independent of it's configuration. If you need to configure your module, adjust on the module side so it is inside that module's `BuildConfig`. You're otherwise creating reverse dependencies that shouldn't exist. Or have the app call `Login.init(this.configNotKnownToTheModule)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same build config values ​​to different modules. Or you can reach the tool by making a module.